# Perl MongoDB geospatial query

Tags: perl, mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to perform a geospatial query with the [MongoDB::Collection](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB%3a%3aCollection#AUTHOR) package for Perl, but it's not working. Does anyone have an example use? Does it even work? There is no specific example in the package documentation and the example [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) on the site isn't working.

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved. It turns out that JSON conversion of some of my data types were off. Which is interesting considering that I'm using Perl.

Answer (score 0):

its only **array** query so you can convert this code to perl:

```
$earthRadius = 6378; // km
$range = 35; // max search km
$max = $range / $earthRadius;

array(
'lat' =>
    array('$within' =>
       array('$centerSphere' =>
          array(array(floatval(  52.417 ), floatval( 16.883 )),
              $range/$earthRadius)
        )
    )
);


$collection->ensureIndex(array('loc.lat' => "2d"), array('background' => true) );
```